# Terminating a subprocess in python flask

Tags: python, flask, process, operating-system, subprocess

I have a flask application in which I have to run a bash script. On visiting a particular link (let say localhost:5000/B) I execute the script using python's subprocess library. Then used wait() function on subprocess. So that the script is finished before doing other tasks which depend on script. After finishing those remaining tasks I return the results in response by rendering a template.

Sometimes I might go back from page or press cancel button( on top side of browser). In that case I want to terminate that script from running even if it has not completed. I have added javascript in page so that when I go back from page it makes a GET request to server at link localhost:5000/C. In the function handling this, I terminate the subprocess.

But due to some reasons it does not work, even after using kill() or terminate() method.

Can we terminate a subprocess on which we have used wait() or not?
If there is a better way of doing this thing kindly let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subprocess was creating another subprocess during the execution and it was creating problems.

Comment: How did you then resolve it? Where is the solution?

Comment: os.system(f'pkill -TERM -P {subProc.pid}')

Comment: subProc = subprocess.run(["somescript.sh", "1" ]).  I used this statement to create subprocess and above statement to terminate it. But my issue was specific in sense that the script was executing some command which it self was creating another subprocess and some how after trying some codes it wasn't terminating. This above os.system... command worked or me